# sort a String array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have a big array like that :

`var tableau = ["Salut", "Hey", "Salut", "Hey", "Hey", "Mom", "Hey", "Dad", "Mom", "Hey", "Plop"]`

And now I want an array with each word sort by the number of repeats so an Array like that :

```
var tableauTrier = ["Hey", "Salut", "Mom", "Dad", "Plop"]
```

How can I use the least memory to sort them ?
Help me please !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var tableau = ["Salut", "Hey", "Salut", "Hey", "Hey", "Mom", "Hey", "Dad", "Mom", "Hey", "Plop"]

var counts = [String: Int]()

// generate dictionary of counts for each word
for word in tableau {
    counts[word] = (counts[word] ?? 0) + 1
}

// Sort the tuples based on the count and use map to extract the word
let result = counts.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }.map { $0.key }
print(result)

// ["Hey", "Mom", "Salut", "Plop", "Dad"]
```

Comment: For better readability since Swift 3 (I think) it can also be written as `counts.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }.map { $0.key }`

Comment: I like that @LeoDabus.  It makes the solution more obviously correct.  A quick check with the IBM Swift Sandbox verifies that this feature did indeed come with Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively – just for fun – a solution with `NSCountedSet`

```
let tableau = ["Salut", "Hey", "Salut", "Hey", "Hey", "Mom", "Hey", "Dad", "Mom", "Hey", "Plop"]
let set = NSCountedSet(array: tableau)
let array = (set.allObjects as! [String]).sorted(by: {set.count(for: $0) > set.count(for: $1)})
print(array) 
// [Hey, Mom, Salut, Dad, Plop]
```

Comment: What a funny solution

Comment: You'll need to make sure `Foundation` is imported.

Comment: @vacawama Yes, but in iOS you will import `UIKit` anyway which includes `Foundation`

Comment: You're resulting array is `[Any]`.  If you need `[String]` you'll want to cast result.

Comment: True, `UIKit` includes `Foundation`, but folks might not `import UIKit` for a model class.

Answer (score 0):

With a little helper array, you can got about it like this:

```
var tableau = ["Salut", "Hey", "Salut", "Hey", "Hey", "Mom", "Hey", "Dad", "Mom", "Hey", "Plop"]
var unique = Array(Set(tableau))
unique.sort { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    let str1Count = tableau.reduce(0, { (result, str) -> Int in
        return  str == str1 ? result+1 : result
    })
    let str2Count = tableau.reduce(0, { (result, str) -> Int in
        return  str == str2 ? result+1 : result
    })
    return str1Count > str2Count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a solution:

```
var result = tableau.sorted(by: { current, next in
    tableau.filter { $0 == current }.count > tableau.filter { $0 == next }.count
}).reduce([String](), {
    if $0.contains($1) {
        return $0
    } else {
        var newPartial = $0
        newPartial.append($1)
        return newPartial
    }
})

print(result)  // ["Hey", "Salut", "Mom", "Dad", "Plop"]
```